# mypy - [mypy-foo.*] does not work in config file

Tags: python, python-3.x, configuration, ini, mypy

My mypy.ini, located in `.../viv/mypy.ini` looks like this:

```lsp
[mypy]
mypy_path = $MYPY_CONFIG_FILE_DIR/stubs
ignore_missing_imports = true
allow_untyped_globals = true
```

**I want those two ignore settings only to apply to a certain subfolder `.../viv/mytypes`**.

I don't want to exclude the folder entirely since I need to know the methods and classes inside it, but I don't care about those mypy issues within it since it's not my code. Can this be done?

---

I've seen something like this:

```lsp
[mypy]
mypy_path = $MYPY_CONFIG_FILE_DIR/stubs

[mypy-mytypes.*]
ignore_missing_imports = true
allow_untyped_globals = true
```

... but that doesn't seem to work, possibly because of the working directory I'm invoking mypy from?

Comment: What working directory are you invoking mypy from?